# Python stdout outputting strange values when using shell redirect; only when doing algebra on inputted data

Tags: python, shell

I made a script to do some simple numerical operations on binary time series data inputted as big endian 4 btye floats, each with a header. It can read in the header, parse the data, then output it in the same form it came in. It would be most convenient if I can pipe data in and out of it from shell so I can keep it in my workflow. Such as:

`file_in < python script.py | another program | etc..`

Right now I have a script that can read in and write the data back to STDOUT without a problem - I can confirm that the data and headers are the same as went in. I can do some simple shifting of the array elements, like np.roll(data), and this is fine too. However, when I try to do anything on the values themselves, like multiply them by 1.0, for instance, the values in the outputted data are no longer correct (they go from ~1e1 to ~1e36 and are completely scrambled). The headers remain fine no in all cases. Please see my code below.

I have tried explicitly setting the array dtype using `data.astype('>f')` to no avail. Not sure what else to try.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
""" 
IN:  STDIN 
OUT: STDOUT
"""
import sys
import numpy as np

while True: #open and write out one trace at a time

    """ IMPORT TRACE HEADER """
    header_data=sys.stdin.read(240) #read in first 240 btyes
    if len(header_data)==0: break

    #open all two and four byte headers
    four_byte = np.fromstring(header_data, dtype='>i4') 
    two_byte=np.fromstring(header_data, dtype='>i2')

    ns=two_byte[57] # ns is necessary to parse in trace data
    dt=two_byte[58]*1e-6 #example 2-byte header from byte 58
    
    """ IMPORT TRACE DATA """
    data=np.fromstring(sys.stdin.read(4*ns), dtype='>f4') #4 bytes per sample
    
    """ INSERT NUMERICAL OPERATIONS HERE """

    data_out = data              # gives a good output
    data_out = np.roll(data,10)  # gives a good output

    data_out = data * 1.            # does not give a good output!
    data_out = data + np.ones((ns)) # does not give a good output!
        
    """ WRITE OUT """
    sys.stdout.write(header_data)
    sys.stdout.write(data_out)
sys.stdout.close()
#END
```

Comment: Performing actual calculations on your data is probably producing output in your computer's native endianness, on the assumption that this is going to be vastly faster in further processing.  You'd need to explicitly convert back to big-endian before writing out the array.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I think you are right, but I tried data.astype('>f') which did not work. However, I just found a work-around now by indexing like this: data_out[0:ns] = data * 1. It must preserve the arrays original endiness as you suggest when doing it this way.

Comment: `data.astype('>f')` by itself wouldn't do anything - you'd need to assign the result.  And it's `data_out` that needs its endianness changed, anyway.